# Selenium how to make click and hold button

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

In webpage I test is a modal which appears after pressing a button for circa 5sec.

And now I'm trying to make this in `selenium`.
I have method like this:

```
public static void ClickHold(IWebElement by)
{
    SpecialInteractions.ClickAndHold(by);
}
```

where

```
public static Actions SpecialInteractions { get; set; }
```

and there is no hold time to set.

It looks like just clicking and releasing. Is there a way to wait for particular amount of time and then release?

Comment: if is it on hover then you can do like hover on element and then use thread.sleep() for specific seconds.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not on hover. User need to click and hold.

Comment: on click it changing page?

Comment: yes. And on clickAndHold it shows modal

Comment: Can I have URL where you trying?

Comment: No. This page isnt deployed anywhere on web. And is way to complex even to try paste it on something like jsfiddle

Answer (score 5):

Without digging dipper I can tell you the program above probably returns `NulReference exception`. I suspect you need to instantiate the `Actions` by wrapping the current driver instance.

Possible solution could be:

```
public void ClickHold(IWebElement element)
{
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(webelement).build().perform();
    //you need to release the control from the test
    //actions.MoveToElement(element).Release();
}
```

Comment: I'm very surry I pasted too little. Actions are of course  instantiate with driver. There is no NullPointerException. This code is just holding and releasing right after because there is no time to set

Comment: Have you tried using some sleep after hold and then `Release()` method?

Comment: @Anonymous_downvoter  Please specify the reason for the downvote. And, specify what I am doing wrong or missing

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(webelement).build().perform();   Add this in your answer to make it work.

Comment: how we can do that in JS?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this will not work if you are using Selenium Grid. There is a bug that makes moveToElement an unrecognized command.

```
public static Boolean moveToThenSlowClickElement(final WebDriver driver, final WebElement toElement, final int millisecondsOfWaitTime) {
        final Actions clickOnElementAndHold = new Actions(driver);
        final Actions release = new Actions(driver);
        clickOnElementAndHold.moveToElement(toElement).clickAndHold(toElement).perform();

        sleep(millisecondsOfWaitTime);

        release.release(toElement).perform();

        final Action hoverOverCheckBox = clickOnElementAndHold.build();
        hoverOverCheckBox.perform();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I was having the same problem with docker selenium grid with moveToElement, however the latest release has moveToElement working again. For me this was just with Firefox/gecko
3.4.0 had FF - 55.0 and gecko 0.18.0 - this was a bad combo for moveToElement, latest has FF 59.0.1 and gecko 0.20.1 - good combo! - Note: While I got moveToElement working for a hover test, I see that it is not working for dragAndDrop - how can this go unfixed for so long?